# Python Dataframe: How to map a column value with adjacent columns value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

map a column value with adjacent columns value using pandas with python
have a df with values

```
name          exm_date                         att_date    
tom       2019-03-05 11:48:03.166             2020-03-05 11:48:03.166 
mark      2018-03-05 11:48:03.166             2020-03-05 11:48:03.166     
matt      2020-08-05 11:48:03.166              NAT
rob       2020-06-05 11:48:03.166              NAT
chuck     2020-02-05 11:48:03.166              NAT
tom       2020-03-05 11:48:03.166              NAT
matt      2020-02-05 11:48:03.166             2020-03-05 11:48:03.166     
chuck     2020-06-05 11:48:03.166             2020-03-05 11:48:03.166
```

for values in att_date having NAT , should pick date from exm_date
expected output :

```
name          exm_date                         att_date    
tom       2019-03-05 11:48:03.166             2020-03-05 11:48:03.166 
mark      2018-03-05 11:48:03.166             2020-03-05 11:48:03.166     
matt      2020-08-05 11:48:03.166             2020-08-05 11:48:03.166 
rob       2020-06-05 11:48:03.166             2020-06-05 11:48:03.166  
chuck     2020-02-05 11:48:03.166             2020-02-05 11:48:03.166
tom       2020-03-05 11:48:03.166             2020-03-05 11:48:03.166
matt      2020-02-05 11:48:03.166             2020-03-05 11:48:03.166     
chuck     2020-06-05 11:48:03.166             2020-03-05 11:48:03.166
```

Comment: if NAT is not a text, and is actually null, ```df.ffill(axis=1)``` will fill att_date with exm_date values on the same row.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.loc` with a boolean to which evaluates to `True` if att_date is null

```
df.loc[df['att_date'].isna(),'att_date'] = df['exm_date']
print(df)
     name          exm_date                att_date
0    tom 2019-03-05 11:48:03.166 2020-03-05 11:48:03.166
1   mark 2018-03-05 11:48:03.166 2020-03-05 11:48:03.166
2   matt 2020-08-05 11:48:03.166 2020-08-05 11:48:03.166
3    rob 2020-06-05 11:48:03.166 2020-06-05 11:48:03.166
4  chuck 2020-02-05 11:48:03.166 2020-02-05 11:48:03.166
5    tom 2020-03-05 11:48:03.166 2020-03-05 11:48:03.166
6   matt 2020-02-05 11:48:03.166 2020-03-05 11:48:03.166
7  chuck 2020-06-05 11:48:03.166 2020-03-05 11:48:03.166
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `fillna` or [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html)

```
df['att_date'] = df['att_date'].fillna(df['exm_date'])
#or
df['att_date'] = df['att_date'].combine_first(df['exm_date'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the apply method to replace missing values:

```py
df['att_date'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: row['exm_date'] if row['att_date'] == 'NAT' else row['att_date'],
    axis=1)
```